# I am trying to use pie chart to show information in percentage using Wikidata

Tags: sparql

I am trying to use a pie chart to show the percentage of tennis players who use their right hand or left hand or both (to show the dominant hand).e.g I just need help with a working query that can show that 50% use their right and 40 percent use their left and 10 percent use both of their hands

```
SELECT (COUNT(?item1) AS ?total)  (100*?item2/?total AS ?percent) 
WHERE { 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?item WHERE {
      ?item1 p:P106 ?statement0.
      ?statement0 (ps:P106/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q10833314.
                   
     ?item2 p:P741 ?statement1.
      ?statement1 (ps:P741/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q789447.
                                        
      ?item2 p:P741 ?statement2.
      ?statement2 (ps:P741/(wdt:P279*)) wd:Q3039938.
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how often do you want to ask this question?

Comment: also, in your subquery you are doing what? Doing a cartesian join of `item1` and `item2`, and then selecting a useless unbound variable `item` - in the outer query you're counting by something that is not know, computing total just based on one type of values ... total is obviously the number of all tennis players or just the sum of number of tennis players per hand type

Comment: also, putting `(wdt:P279*)` everywhere is just weird - do you understand the meaning and purpose? I mean, that is not appropriate nor necessary to use in any triple pattern

Comment: `SELECT * 
WITH {
 SELECT DISTINCT ?s {
?s p:P106/ps:P106/wdt:P279* wd:Q10833314 
  }
} AS %results
{
{SELECT (count(?s) as ?left) { 
  INCLUDE %results.
  ?s p:P741/ps:P741 wd:Q789447.
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?s p:P741/ps:P741 wd:Q3039938.}
}}
  {SELECT (count(?s) as ?right) { 
  INCLUDE %results.        
  ?s p:P741/ps:P741 wd:Q3039938. 
  FILTER NOT EXISTS {?s p:P741/ps:P741 wd:Q789447.}
      
}}
  {SELECT (count(?s) as ?both) { 
  INCLUDE %results.                         
  ?s p:P741/ps:P741 wd:Q789447, wd:Q3039938.                                             
}}
}`

Comment: I asked again because your first solution didn't work and I wanted to re edit the post and see if others have an idea of this. As for your new solution you sent , it only displays to me the number of players that use specific hands and not the percentage

Comment: computing the percentage of a number is trivial, no? just get all tennis players in a separate query or simply sum up left, right and both sided player numbers. Rendering of percentages is client side aka UI code anyways